# Connect NSImageView to view using IB?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xcode, macos

I've only programmed on the iPhone so far, so Cocoa is sort of confusing in certain ways for me.  Here's where I've hit a snag.  I wanted my window so that the background was invisible, and without a title-bar.  Something like this:

[image]

Here's how I'm doing it:

I set my `window`'s class to a custom window, which I've created like this:

### CustomWindow.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>


@interface CustomWindow : NSWindow {
    @private
    NSPoint initialLocation;
}

@property(assign)NSPoint initialLocation;

@end
```

### CustomWindow.m

```
//trimmed to show important part
#import "CustomWindow.h"

@implementation CustomWindow
@synthesize initialLocation;

- (id)initWithContentRect:(NSRect)contentRect styleMask:(NSUInteger)aStyle backing:(NSBackingStoreType)bufferingType defer:(BOOL)flag {
    // Removes the window title bar
    self = [super initWithContentRect:contentRect styleMask:NSBorderlessWindowMask backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered defer:NO];
    if (self != nil) {
        [self setAlphaValue:1.0];
        [self setOpaque:NO];
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

Now, in my `.xib` file for this window I've added a custom view onto the window.  I've set the view class to a custom class I've created that inherits from `NSView`.  Here's how I'm setting that up:

### MainView.h

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface MainView : NSView {
@private
//nothing to see here, add later
}

@end
```

### MainView.m

```
//trimmed greatly again to show important part
#import "MainView.h"

@implementation MainView

- (id)initWithFrame:(NSRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)rect {
    // Clear the drawing rect.
    [[NSColor clearColor] set];
    NSRectFill([self frame]);

}

@end
```

So here's my question.  I've added a `NSImageView` to my custom view (`MainView`) in Interface Builder.  However, for some reason I can't figure out how to connect this image view to an instance variable in my custom view.  They seem like they can't be connected like I normally would if I was creating an iPhone app.  Any ideas how this would be done?

Comment: Would I have to create the `NSImageView` in code, instead of IB?  It might make life much easier...

Comment: You’ve said you want to connect an image view to an instance variable in your custom view. However, the declaration of `MainView` does not contain any instance variable (or declared property) at all, much less an `IBOutlet`. Have you posted the complete declaration of `MainView`?

Comment: @Bavarious Sorry, that got clipped out of the code when I copied it.  Even when it was added, IB didn't see it.

Comment: Would you mind pasting the complete declaration of `MainView`? There might be something wrong there.

Comment: @Bavarious Sure, I can post it but it will have to be tomorrow, as I don't  have access to my code right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You connect objects created in your XIB in Mac OS X the same way you do for iOS programs.  Just add an NSImageView property to your main view, mark it as an IBOutlet and connect it up.

For example,

In MainView.h create a property for your NSImageView and make it an IBOutlet:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface MainView : NSView {
  NSImageView *imageView;
}

@property(retain) IBOutlet NSImageView *imageView;

@end
```

In interface builder, make sure the class for the custom view is set to MainView, to do this click on the File's Owner object in the custom view XIB and then select the identity option in the inspector and enter MainView as the class type.

Next, CTRL+click File's owner and drag the arrow to the NSImageView and select the imageView outlet.

That's all there is to it.  You should be able to reference the image view from code now.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  It ended up being an Xcode 4 bug where it had switched back to the previous class that the view was set to before, which was merely `NSView`.  Resetting the class enabled it to see the instance variable, thus allowing the connection.  Thanks for your help!